# How to use STD::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator with relative path?

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++14, c++17, c++-experimental

I’m trying to use the recursive_directory_iterator in filesystem, but I’m getting an error message. My main.cpp file is in “A/main.cpp” file, but I want to access a bunch of .txt files in “B/“. Both A & B folders are located in the same level directory. So, I’m assuming the relative path to B from A is : “./B/“ or “../B/“

Here’s my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 //Absolute path works

    for (auto& file : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator("/Users/Tonny/Desktop/Project/B/"))
    {
        cout<< “Through absolute path: “ << file.path() << endl;
    }
//Relative path doesn’t work
    for (auto& file : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator("../B/"))
    {
        cout << “Through relative path: “ << file.path() << endl;
    }
}
```

However, I’m getting the following error When trying both:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::__fs::filesystem::filesystem_error: filesystem error: in recursive_directory_iterator: No such file or directory [../B]

Here's my compiler version:

```
gcc --version

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: Can you provide the full code? The `recursive_directory_iterator` works on the relative path. https://godbolt.org/z/h31vsv

Comment: Also provide the compiler-version / STL-version and the exact command line to compile your program. Also, the relative path does not depend on the path of the executable or the source file itself, it's always the place where you executed the executable.
E.g., when you open your executable in `/home/user >` with `myApp/A/app` it will try to find ../B in `/home/user/../B` which is in normalized form `/home/B` and not `/home/user/myApp/B`.

Comment: If the directory you want (B) is a sibling of directory (A) you should be able to  use "../B/" to go up one directory and down another.  The slashes may be platform dependent so you should use the file building operations to construct the path.

Example source code will help identify the specific problem.

Comment: Can you replace `<experimental/filesystem>` with `<filesystem>`?

Comment: The preferred path separator is not an issue on Posix and on modern Windows(since NT or Vista I am not sure). Also, the fs::path handles that for you, Don't worry about that.

I would rather use c++17 or even c++20, since the experimental fs was in a draft state and changed a lot. No reason to use a 6-year-old standard in 2020 ;).

Comment: Is the executable in the same directory as the source file? Plus why are you using `experimental` header when the `recursive_directory_iterator` belongs to non-experimental `std::filesystem`?

Answer (score 1):

set the current path first. the system assumes the currently set path when the param to `recursive_directory_iterator(...)` is empty or a relative path.

```
std::filesystem::current_path("/Users/Tonny/Desktop/Project/B/");  //set cur path first

for (auto& file : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator("../B/"))
{
    cout << “Through relative path: “ << file.path() << endl;
}
```

**alternative:**

if you don't want messing up the `current_path()`, atleast track your target path and then concat relative paths to that path-string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
    
    std::string targetPath = "/Users/Tonny/Desktop/Project/B/";

    
     //Absolute path
    for (auto& file : fs:recursive_directory_iterator(targetPath))
    {
        cout<< “Through absolute path: “ << file.path() << endl;
    }
    
    //Relative path
    for (auto& file : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(targetPath + "../B/"))
    {
        cout << “Through relative path: “ << file.path() << endl;
    }
}
```